# How to add columns to a specific folder in SharePoint 2016 document library?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, 2016, ootb

I have one document library and inside it, have 4 folders.

[image]

I want to upload a document to a specific folder with custom metadata/ column values.

In my case, I want to upload a document in "Key Email correspondence" folder with Date, From, To and Subject as metadata

In a similar way, other folders have other custom metadata(s). 
how can we achieve this in SharePoint 2016 OOTB?

Comment: And why aren't you creating separate document libraries for these folders. The documents should reside in a document library if the metadata matches, if it doesn't match; they shouldn't live together.

Comment: I have other libraries also, with multiple folders, these folders also required different metadata. creating multiple libraries will create the mess.

Comment: I have this exact question, this only place I have found this question. Has anyone resolved this?

Comment: As per my knowledge, this is not possible in SP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom folder content type and change the "Key Email correspondence" folder to your custom folder content type.

Then add columns you needed in this custom folder content type.

After that, the specific folder will contain specific columns.

Comment: Already tried that option. but in this case, metadata stuck with folder only not with the document.
e.g. You can create the folder with these metadata but when you are going to upload a document it will ask you to add a name to the document only.

Answer (score 0):

Did you explore using Document Sets? Maybe, this content type will save your time. Document Sets allows setting default values in some columns and export automatically to documents that are inside. [Introduction to Document Sets](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Document-Sets-C49C246D-31F1-4BFE-AFE2-E26698B47E05)

In addition, you have an option on your library called "Column default value settings" that lets you define column values for documents depending on the folder where you upload it. [How to set default column values on a document in SharePoint](https://www.collaboris.com/how-to-set-default-column-values-on-a-document-in-sharepoint/)

If you are searching for different columns for different folders you should think on extending Folder content type and create your owns setting the columns you need for each of them. Then, configure the library with these new content types.

Comment: I tried the document set as well but it adds the columns in each folder while uploading the document. Folder content type is also not suitable for my requirement.
this is a very basic scenario, there must be something which I am missing.

Comment: I think you should create different libraries as @Arsalan Adam Khatri commented on your question. Otherwise, please, describe in more detail your needs or the requirements for that behavior.